# Check assemblies related to Package Reference in VS2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, .net-4.7.2

What is the easiest way to check which files will be included in .NET project when using PackageReference? In my project like on the image below I'm not able to expand them and Properties window is showing nothing!

[image]

Comment: Can you find `your_dll_name.deps.json` file?

Comment: No, only `project.assets.json`

Answer (score 0):

It seam that Visual Studio 2017 is having problems to properly display Package references when old csproj style is used. I solved problem by converting csproj to new SDK style. [Here](https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/) are some instructions which helped me.